# how to setup subdomains for AWS EC2 Ubuntu Instance?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, subdomain, linux-networking

I am trying to setup subdomains for my **AWS EC2 ubuntu instance**, but without enough knowledge I couldn't proceed anymore.

1. I have a parked domain name **example.com** on a domain name service provider.
2. My EC2 instance has **Elastic IP** associated, say **10.10.10.10**
3. I created two A Recoards in the domain name service provider's website.

   **www.example.com**  points to **10.10.10.10**

   **example.com**  points to **10.10.10.10**
4. everything is working like a charm , i can access my Instance with the domain name.

But now I would like to have **subdomain** for **individual websites/services** for the instance, say **webmail.example.com**, **database.example.com**.

I tried to setup Virtual Host file for sub-domains, but it didn't work when I accessed those subdomains , chrome said "**Oops! Google Chrome could not find subdoamin.example.com**"

**Q:** My question is, how can I set up subdomains for my server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it should work with name based virtual hosting in apache , please provide your apache config file.

Comment: one quick question have you created A record in DNS for your other subdomain pointing to ip 10.10.10.10?

Comment: HI Abhishek, i haven't created any subdomain Records in DNS. Is it necessary to do it? If I have 100+ subdomains, do i have to add them on the the DNS records? thanks

Comment: yes you need to add A record for each and every subdomain in your DNS in order to access your website publically with Domain name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By far the easiest way to do this is to create a [wildcard DNS record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) for example.com. for example

```
*.example.com. 14400 A 10.10.10.10
```

or a CNAME

```
*.example.com CNAME example.com.
```

Remember that Apache will serve the content of the first vhost whose [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) or [Serveralias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) matched the [Host: header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) in the http request. If none of these match then the content of the first vhost defined is served as it is considered the default vhost.

To get apache to server content the easiest way is to use [NameBasedVirtual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) hosting.

If you want to server the same content from each vhost then just define one

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

If you want to serve different (but the same) content from sub1.example.com and sub2.example.com then you could do something line this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub1.example.com
    ServerAlias sub2.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub1sub2
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

and so on.

If you have many of vhosts to setup and configure you may want to have a look at Apache's [Dynamically configured mass hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html) documentation.